# .NET API & IIS & localhost

Tags: asp.net, .net, api

I have configure an API on Visual Studio using C# when I run the API it works.

I have tried to move the API over to my server, when I launch the API it says the following

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

And with that, I can only access this using http://localhost:5000 or http://127.0.0.1:5000 - I am unable to use my servers IP address(http://10.5.0.2:5000) or a domain name.

What advice can you give me.

Comment: What bindings did you configure in IIS? If things aren't working, you need to describe the related configuration.

Comment: I have *:80 and *:443

Comment: So, what happens when you navigate to your app at those ports?

Comment: I have added :5000 to my bindings
Failed to bind to address http://localhost:5000

Comment: No, that wouldn't make sense to add a binding for port 5000. ASP.NET Core runs Kestrel, which listens on localhost:5000. IIS takes the incoming requests (based on the bindings) and will forward them to your app running on localhost:5000. That's should all be transparent to you, you don't have to add bindings for port 5000 for that to work. So, why don't you actually describe the configuration work you've done, and tell us precisely what's happening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem
I uninstalled IIS(or some of it) and reinstalled it.

Deleted all my Sites and started fresh.

When I ran the app it worked :-)